# Is possible to get type a child class type from base class?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

I need something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    T commonData;
    TYPEOF_CHILD_CLASS *test(T data)
    {
        return new CHILD_CLASS(data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    T bdata;
    B(T data)
    {
        bdata = data;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class C : public A<T>
{
public:
    T cdata;
    C(T data)
    {
        cdata = data;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto a = C<int>(1).test(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Is possible to define TYPEOF_CHILD_CLASS in c++? Before I used D. In D it works with:

```
R (this R) test(T data)
{
   return new R(data);
}
...

void main()
{
    auto a = new C!A(1).test(2);
}
```

It is a template. Does the c++ have a similar method? Maybe can I set type also via a template? Or may be I determine typename via `typeid`?

Comment: [The curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Comment: would it be ok if `B` and `C` do not inherit from a common base? In the posted code there is no common interface. CRTP is an option

Comment: Or polymorphism, making `test` virtual, returning a pointer to the base-class `A`, and override in the child class to return `new C`? It all kind of depends on the use-case and the actual problem you're trying to solve with your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Some programmer dude @463035818_is_not_a_number. In according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) link it works.

```cpp
template <class T, typename TT>
class A
{
public:
    TT commonData;
    T *test(TT data)
    {
        return new T(data);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<B<T>, T>
{
public:
    T bdata;
    B(T data)
    {
        bdata = data;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class C : public A<C<T>, T>
{
public:
    T cdata;
    C(T data)
    {
        cdata = data;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto a = C<int>(1).test(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).